# How do I target the every third div with a certain class that is wrapped with an anchor tag?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can I target every 3rd div and give it a certain style? Before I inserted the `<a>` tag, my code worked fine, but I don't know why it isn't working now:

```
<div class="post-row clearfix">
    <a href="">
        <div class="recent-post post-1">
            <div class="recent-post-info">
                <p>Three Apple Pi Students Win Physics Video Award</p>
            </div><!-- recent-post-info -->
        </div><!-- recent-post -->
    </a>

    <a href="">
        <div class="recent-post post-2">
            <div class="recent-post-info">
                <p>Robot on Mars &mdash; 3 years later</p>
            </div><!-- recent-post-info -->
        </div><!-- recent-post -->
    </a>

    <a href="">
        <div class="recent-post post-3">
            <div class="recent-post-info">
                <p>Second Annual "Spooktacular" cruise in</p>
            </div><!-- recent-post-info -->
        </div><!-- recent-post -->
    </a>

</div><!-- post-row -->
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.post-row{
    padding: 0 15%;
}

.recent-post{
    width: 31.33333333%;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 3% 40px 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: table;
}

.recent-post-info{
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: rgba(109, 109, 109, .85);
}     

.recent-post:nth-child(3n){
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because each `div.recent-post`  is the child of a single anchor, so the third does not exist.

Target the third anchor, then it's `div`

```
.post-row a:nth-child(3) .recent-post
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was playing around with it but I guess I missed this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a class on each anchor tag and target the anchor tag instead of the nested div tag ?